# Testing ViewModel in Android with Koin and Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, koin

I started using Koin and I need to test a ViewModel that asks the Repository to retrieve a file from the internal storage of the phone.

When I'm setting the ViewModel test up, I'm doing:

```
@Before
    fun setup() {
        startKoin {
            modules(dataModule)
        }
        declareMock<Repository> {
            fakeAccount = moshiAccountAdapter.fromJson(json)
            whenever(this.getAccount()).thenReturn(fakeAccount)
        }
    }
```

but the repository `getAccount` method is `suspend fun getAccount(): Account?`, so I'm getting an error in the `ViewModelTest` class saying `suspend function getAccount should be called only from a coroutine or from another suspending function`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `runBlocking { }` block to run suspended functions for test purposes

Comment: where exactly do you mean that I should do this?

Comment: `fun setUp() = runBlocking{ ...}` or anywhere between suspended function invocation. This block will actually wtart a coroutine, I suggest to read about it to get deeper knowlegde or coroutines that will helpmyou greatly

Comment: I've tried that already, and AS says `suspension functions can be called only within corutine body`

Comment: well I just moved that stubbing to the test, which is inside a `runBlockingTest` and thus it works now, thanks!